# How do I extract the table in the below plaintext as a pandas dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a set of texts as below. I want to extract these the table formatted in these plain texts as a pandas dataframe.

What I have:

"data.txt"

```
Description:           Daily Index of EDGAR Dissemination Feed by Form Type
Last Data Received:    July 01, 1994
Discussion List:       edgar-interest@town.hall.org
To Subscribe to List:  Majordomo@town.hall.org
General Information:   info@radio.com
E-mail server:         mail@town.hall.org
Anonymous FTP:         ftp://town.hall.org/edgar/daily-index/form.070194.idx

Form Type   Company Name            CIK         Date Filed  File Name 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10-C        ABC.                    310254      19940701    file1.txt   
10-B        XYZ.                    121234      54547474    file2.txt   
10-A        LMN.                    346765      12352356    file3.txt
```

What I want: a pandas dataframe with below structure

```
Form Type   Company Name     CIK          Date Filed   File Name 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| 10-C      | ABC          | 310254     | 19940701   | file1.txt  | 
| 10-B      | XYZ          | 121234     | 54547474   | file2.txt  |
| 10-A      | LMN          | 346765     | 12352356   | file3.txt  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Below is my code:

```
test = test.split('\n')
while not re.search('^--*', test[0]): test.pop(0)
test.pop(0)

rows = []
for row in test:
  rows.append(row.split())

print(rows)
```

I find the first occurrence of the dashed line and then append the rows to a list. Later I convert it to a dataframe. However, I believe there must be a cleaner way to do this, which is why I ask your contribution/support.

Comment: Does that text always start with 7 extra lines?

Comment: Not particularly 7. It may vary.

Answer (score 4):

Find the empty line that separates the starting extra lines from the needed table structure, then pass the remaining file buffer to [`pd.read_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_table.html) function:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
     for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:  # find empty line
            break
     df = pd.read_table(f, sep='\s{2,}', header=0, comment='--', engine='python')
     print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Form Type Company Name     CIK  Date Filed  File Name
0      10-C         ABC.  310254    19940701  file1.txt
1      10-B         XYZ.  121234    54547474  file2.txt
2      10-A         LMN.  346765    12352356  file3.txt
```

Comment: It fails for some rows which have words separated from more than 2 spaces.

Comment: @ItsKirA, by "words" you mean column names or column values?

Comment: Words inside the columns. for example. "Company ABC     Ltd."

Comment: @ItsKirA, I've checked, it will not fail when a column contains  such value as  "Company ABC Ltd."

Answer (score 0):

we have a method pd.read_fwf(), where you can give parameter to skip records from being part of dataframe like -
no of lines to skip initial records
blank records

If you know in advance from where data will start then use this function to read file.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something along the lines of:

```py
from io import StringIO

input_string = 'the content of my text file (PLEASE REPLACE)' # TODO replace with actual content or code to load the content
nr_of_seperators = 20 # number of '-' in seperator line (I just assumed 20, I did not count)
mystring = input_string.split('-' * nr_of_seperators)
header_split_from_data = mystring.split(delimiter=mystring)

# create columns assuming there is always at least two spaces between column names
headerlines = header_split_from_data[0].split('\n') # split the lines
columns = headerlines[-1].split() # extract the column names from the last line of the header 

# create csv string from data assuming the data does not contain strings with spaces
lines = header_split_from_data[1].split('\n') # seperate lines
csv_string_lines = [','.join(line.split()) for line in lines] # this splits the string on whitespaces
csv_string = '\n'.join(csv_string_lines)

# load dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_string), sep=",", header=None, names=columns)
```

There might be an easier and more efficient way to do this, but this is what came to my mind as an easy-to-implement (haters will call it quick and dirty :D) version.